# Issue with URL Path of child category after change URL key of Parent category

Tags: magento-2.1, category, url, url-key

I have an issue with URL path of child categories. I have changed URL key of the category , but still child category URL path with old URL key of the parent category.

On the category page, i am displaying child categories of the current category.

For example, i have Car is parent category. Previous URL key was car after I have changed it to car-type but still child category `i.e www.example.com/car/suv.html`

It should be `www.example.com/car-type/suv.html`

I am getting url by `$category->getUrl()`

Comment: I have faced same issue. Do you have got any solution. Please share the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve url issue, follow the URL: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites.